# Stored Procedures using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, stored-procedures

Can you please advice on how to execute a stored procedure using the CodeIgniter Framework? I looked into the User Guide and was only able to find ways to access the DB using queries or ActiveRecords. Appreciate if someone could assist at the earliest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->db->query("call my_stored_proc('arg1','arg2');")`.

if you have out parameters you have to wrap it in a transaction like so:

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->trans_start();

$success = $this->db->query("call my_stored_proc('arg1','arg2',@out_param);");
$out_param_query = $this->db->query('select @out_param as out_param;');

$this->db->trans_complete();

$out_param_row = $this->db->row();
$out_param_val = $this->out_param;
```

Comment: Will this help me retrieve multiple rows as well?

Comment: You can get multiple rows from a stored proc call if you have a select statement inside, however, if you have multiple select statements inside, you will probably only get one set, IIRC it uses `mysqli_query` instead of `mysqli_multi_query`