# Get Data From Stored Procedure Using Sqlsrv Driver

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter, rest, stored-procedures

I am using `SQL server2008` as database and I have written stored procedure in `MSSQL Server 2008`. It's working fine in `MSSQL Server 2008`. I want to call this Stored Procedure from `codeigniter`. For that I wrote the code like this :

**phpService.php:**

```
public function Login($username, $password)
{
    $this->load->model('Apimodel');
    $result = $this->Apimodel->Login($username,$password);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('LoginResponce'=>$result));
}
```

**apimodel.php:**

```
function Login($UserName,$Password)
{               
    $this->db = $this->GetDB();
    $query =  $this->db->query("EXEC Login");

    return $query->result();

}
```

**when I Execute Procedure without parameter it Working Fine**

```
function Login($UserName,$Password)
    {               
        $this->db = $this->GetDB();
        $query =  $this->db->query("EXEC Login '$UserName','$Password'");

        return $query->result();

    }
```

**But, When I Execute Procedure with parameter it's not working**

Can anyone tell me What am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this might help http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/202515/

Comment: @Deepanshu : I am not getting from this link. can you explain me  ?

Comment: Have you tried using bound parameters? `$this->db->query("Exec Login ?, ?", array($UserName, $Password));` That will prevent errors if the password has a quote character in it.

Comment: did you try $this->db->query("EXEC Login('$UserName','$Password')");

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928751/stored-procedures-using-codeigniter

Comment: he he dude I tried that link already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh..............after long RND I got ans

**PhpService.php:**

```
    public function Login($username, $password)
    {

        $this->load->model('Apimodel');
        $result = $this->Apimodel->Login($username,$password);

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('LoginResponce'=>$result));

    }
```

**apimodel.php:**

```
function Login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db = $this->GetDB();
        $query =  $this->db->query("EXEC Login $username,$password");

        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using Codeigniter, I recommend use their database class to connect to MSSQL Server. You can read more on this here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

If you aren't auto-connecting to your database you can connect like this: `$this->load->database('default');`

Once you have your configuration setup, you can have a function like this in your model:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    return $this->db->query("EXEC spLogin '$username', '$password'")->result();
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in \apimodel.php on line 87 ...$query = $this->db->query("EXEC Common_Login($username, $password)");

Comment: Sounds like you're still not using CI's database classes. Make sure you read up on it and models: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html. And make sure you enclose your strings in single quotes.

Comment: When I am Execute procedure without parameter then it will working fine but with parameter it's not working proper

Comment: Are you putting quotes around your parameters? Take the whole query string and run it in MSSQL Server to see if there are any errors: echo "EXEC Common_Login('$username', '$password')"

Comment: I use `$this->db->query()` to run stored procedures very often. What happens now when you run your query? Do you get an error? Does the query look right if you inspect `$this->db->last_query()`?

Comment: This isn't part of Codeigniter: `$this->db = $this->GetDB();`. Ensure you are connecting to your database properly and remove that line. Codeigniter will set `$this->db` once you're connected.