# How to find a last inserted value from procedure in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am trying get a last inserted value but I'm getting the error:

> "Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE hssl.insert_brouchermaster; expected 2, got 3"

Procedure

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `brouchermaster`(`broucher_name`,`order_number`) VALUES (brouchername,orderno,NOW());
SET @inserted_instance_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Model:

```
$insert_result = $this->db->query("CALL insert_brouchermaster('".$broucher_name."', '".$order_number."', @inserted_instance_id)");
$last_insert_query = $this->db->query("SELECT @inserted_instance_id");
```

Comment: Read the error, in procedure you have two columns but three values `NOW()` is the third

Comment: I have not used SPs in CI, but doesn't last_insert_id() work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI function `db->query('your query here')` returns either true or false so it isn't going to return @inserted_instance_id for you. I think you'll need to change

```
$insert_result = $this->db->query("CALL insert_brouchermaster('".$broucher_name."', '".$order_number."', @inserted_instance_id)");
```

to this

```
$this->db->query("CALL insert_brouchermaster('".$broucher_name."', '".$order_number."'");
//and add this line
$new_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

That said, I've not had not used stored procedures very often, and not for awhile, so my syntax may be faulty. Never the less, use `insert_id()` to get what your after.

Documentation on the function [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

Also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928751/stored-procedures-using-codeigniter)